# Finds elements to the right of the given element on a 4x4 board

Tags: list, list-comprehension

I'm currently flabbergasted with a seemingly easy problem.

I've got a 4x4 board with sequentially ordered elements, like so:

```
1  2   3  4    
5  6   7  8
9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

And I want to write list comprehensions that, given a direction and element, a list will be returned with all elements in the given direction.
For example: given direction North for element 10 would give 6 and 2.
I've got 3 directions nailed, North, South and West but I can't figure out East.

My list comprehensions for the 3 I've got are, with Id being the element in question and List a list from 1 to 16:

```
     North->
        [ X | X <- List, X < Id, (Id-X) mod 4 == 0]
    South ->
        [ X | X <- List, X > Id, (Id-X) mod4 == 0]
    West ->
        [ X | X <- List, X < Id, X > ((Id-1) div 4)*4]
```

I can't find a valid equation for East. Any help?

Edit:

East 14 should give 15 and 16 for example. East 16 should give the empty list. I'm really stumped.

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: I'd like to make it in Erlang, but this is more pseudo code. Normally it should be readable for everybody with experience in functional languages. If it isn't please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem is using division and modulo to tell which numbers are on the same lines.

If two values have the same modulo result, then they are on the same column. If they are less than the given value, then they are north. If they are more than the given value, they are south.

In general, if two values have the same integer result of division, they should be on the same row. This would always be true for 0-based squares; however, this example uses a square that starts at 1. Instead of testing the division results of the given value and the numbers on the board, subtract 1 from the given value and the test value, then divide and compare results.

Psuedo code

```
given = 10
for x in board:
    if int( (given - 1) / 4 ) equals int( (x - 1) / 4 ):
        if x < given:
            x is west
        if x > given:
            x is east
```

Here is a sample function written in Python

```
import math
def figure(board, num, dir):
    dir = dir.lower()
    sq = math.sqrt(len(board))
    if sq != int(sq) or num not in board:
        return "invalid sqaure"

    if dir == "n":
        return [x for x in board if x < num and x%sq == num%sq] 
    elif dir == "s":
        return [x for x in board if x > num and x%sq == num%sq]
    elif dir == "e":
        return [x for x in board if x > num and int((x-1)/sq) == int((num-1)/sq)]
    elif dir == "w":
        return [x for x in board if x < num and int((x-1)/sq) == int((num-1)/sq)]
    else:
        return "invalid direction"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the Esat shold be:

```
ESAT->    

 [ X | X <- List, X >Id, X <= ⌈Id / 4)⌉ * 4  ]
```